# ImageMagick count how many identical or almost identical color pixels are on the edges left and right of image

Tags: imagemagick

This is an example PNG image:

[image]

it's 50x40 but enlarged here to see it better.

The hex of bottom left and bottom right pixels is `F9E4B7`

I need to know how many pixels there are on vertical edges from the bottom left and right with almost this color, like 1% fuzz because they are not all exactly `F9E4B7` but some are very slightly different.

In this case it would be 20px of each side:

I'll mark the areas which need to be counted just to make it perfectly clear:

[image]

I also need to be able to count how many pixels are exactly `F9E4B7`,  which in this case would be  15 left and 20 right, I'll mark the slightly different areas so it's clear where the counter needs to stop:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do that in Imagemagick is to use fuzz to change all your pixels close to that color to white and the rest black. The crop the first or last column and use -fx to get the count from mean*width*height. So for example for the left full column of the whole image, one has

Unix Imagemagick 6 syntax:

```
convert tan.png -alpha off \
-fuzz 1% -fill white -opaque "#F9E4B7" -fill black +opaque white \
-gravity west -crop 1x+0+0 -format "%[fx:round(mean*w*h)]\n" info:
```

Windows Imagemagick Syntax:

```
convert tan.png -alpha off ^
-fuzz 1% -fill white -opaque "#F9E4B7" -fill black +opaque white ^
-gravity west -crop 1x+0+0 -format "%[fx:round(mean*w*h)]\n" info:
```

Result:

```
108
```

To get the right side, use -gravity east.

For exact count, use -fuzz 0

For Imagemagick 7, change `convert` to `magick`

Comment: Yessss thank you very much!! You saved me a ton of workaround!!

Comment: -fuzz 0 doesn't work though? I get 0

Comment: Nice answer. Note that it will also match and count pixels of that colour at the edges in the upper part of the image - no idea if that matters.

Comment: Maybe try `+fuzz` instead of `-fuzz 0`

Comment: @MarkSetchell yeah I already guessed that but that will lead to maybe 2 out of 100 images not perfectly processed instead of like 1 out of 100 if it would be counter from the bottom so it doesn't really matter :D

Comment: +fuzz gives also 0, hmm

Comment: I make the bottom-left pixel #F6E2B5 for some reason.

Comment: I did not measure. I assumed he knows what values he wants.